# Does the continuous mapping space between topological manifolds always admit a Banach manifold structure?

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, differential-topology, banach-manifold, mapping-space

Let $M$ and $N$ be smooth, i.e. $C^\infty$, manifolds. Suppose that $M$ is compact. Then for every $k \geq 0$ it is well known that $$C^k(M,N)$$ admits the structure of a smooth Banach manifold. I am interested in the continuous case, i.e. $k = 0$. I think that then one can drop the regularity of $M$ and $N$ and still get a Banach manifold $$C(M,N)$$ as one constructs the charts via an exponential map. **My question**: Is $C(M,N)$ a Banach manifold also in the case where $M$ and $N$ are merely topological manifolds, i.e. $C^0$ manifolds? I mean if $M$ and $N$ admit a $C^1$ structure or equivalently a $C^\infty$ structure, then the statement is obvious, but this is not always the case.

Comment: If $M$ is a compact metric space, and $N$ is a $C^k$ Banach manifold, the space $C^0(M,N)$ is a $C^k$ Banach manifold. No other assumptions are required.

Comment: See the reference to the Tausk's paper in the answer here: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/121107/banach-manifold

Answer (score 0):

Let $U$ and $V$ be open domains of $\mathbb R^n$. If $h:U \to V$ is a homeomorphism, then the map
$$\mathcal C^0(M,U) \to \mathcal C^0(M,V)$$
sending $f$ to $h\circ f$ is a homeomorphism between open subsets of a Banach space. If $h$ is a $\mathcal C^1$ diffeomorphism, then $f\mapsto h\circ f$ is a diffeomorphism.

Doesn't it show (with some work) that $\mathcal C^0(M,N)$ is a $\mathcal C^1$ Banach manifold when $N$ is $\mathcal C^1$ and a "topological Banach manifold" when $N$ is only $\mathcal C^0$?

Comment: How would it show?